# Is it possible to have a view have the same primary key as its underlying table?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE item (id int PRIMARY KEY, name text, price numeric);
```

I am able to run queries such as

```
SELECT COUNT(*), id, name, price FROM item GROUP BY id;
```

I assume because `id` is the primary key of the table, even though `name` and `price` are not in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Now suppose I create a view on the `item` table as so:

```
CREATE VIEW item_view AS SELECT * from item;
```

If I try to run the same query against this view, it doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), id, name, price FROM item_view GROUP BY id;
```

> ERROR:  column "item_view.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

And I assume this is because the `item_view` view does not respect the primary key constraint of its underlying `item` table.

I guess I have two questions here:

1. Is there a way I can make the last query on the view valid so that it is equivalent to the first query?
2. Is it bad practice to group by the primary key and then select whatever fields I want?

Comment: `I can not make a similar query as above like` Why not?  BTW: run both queries, and compare the query-plans. (They will be equal)

Comment: It doesn't work because the item_view does not respect id being the primary key since views cannot have primary keys. I get the error:
column "item_view.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: I see. Well, it's a bad habit anyway. And count(*) will always be `1`

Comment: Well this isn't the actual query I'm using, the point of the count(*) is to illustrate that an aggregate function is being used, which is why the group by is being used in the first place. It could be any aggregate function.

Comment: Please show your actual query; the query you present confuses me.

Comment: @Laurenz: Confused me too, but I think we just needed the error message; given that context, this seems like a pretty good self-contained example.